# TFS Project Template create from existing Template issue

Tags: tfs

I need to create new TFS project template using existing template. i just rename and edited **TypeDefinitions** and tried to upload it. But it said its already exists. how to edit this as a new project template. please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean import Process Template?

If it is, then you need to modify the Process Template `name` and `Version type ID`:

[image]

Comment: Yes, open the `ProcessTemplate.xml` file with text editor, then change the ID freely, just make sure the ID is unique, that means there isn't the same ID in other existing process templates... e.g. change `6B724908-EF14-45CF-84F8-768B53840919` to `6B724908-EF14-45CF-84F8-768B53842018` (just need to change part of them)